# \shoveleft{thanks\ man} doesn't shove both words?

Tags: amsmath, multline

This code

```
\begin{multline*}
hello\\
dear\\
\shoveright{how\ are\ you}\\
\shoveleft{thanks\ man}
\end{multline*}
```

is displayed as

[image]

My question is why not `thanks man` both words are shoved on left like `how are you` are all shoved right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation `amsldoc.pdf` says:

> It's possible to force one of the middle lines to the left or right
>   with commands `\shoveleft`, `\shoveright`.

However, the command `\shoveleft` is used in the last line. The documentation says about the last line:

> The first line of a `multline` will be at the left margin and the last
>   line at the right margin, except for an indention on both sides in the
>   amount of `\multlinegap`.

Nevertheless, as workaround, `\hfill` at the end of the argument of `\shoveleft` fixes the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
hello\\
dear\\
\shoveright{how\ are\ you}\\
\shoveleft{thanks\ man\hfill}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]